# Apache Solr indexing documents error possible analysis error after I renamed manage_schema.xml with schema.xml

Tags: solr

I used Solr 9.4.0 to implement my own Solr search engine but ended up with the above strange errors even though I didn't change anything on managed-schema.xml and just renamed it with manually editable schema.xml file:

1. Most of my raw documents are PDF files which do not have JSON, XML or CSV formatted contents. They are just plain text files. Some are generated from our own CRM report formats.
2. I renamed managed_schema.xml as schema.xml and modified the solrconfig.xml file to replace the schemaFactory class, remove any ManagedIndexSchemaFactory definition, used ClassIndexSchemaFactory.
3. I didn't do any change on the schema.xml which was originally from managed_schema.xml.
4. I restarted the solr server and reload the collection.
5. After I indexed my documents with the above schema.xml, I got many errors at the response:

SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: {
"responseHeader":{
"status":400,
"QTime":2
},
"error":{
"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","java.lang.NullPointerException"],
"msg":"Exception writing document id C:\Solr\saletent\USA\CA\xxxfolder\2019\Tutelage\P12714 somefilename.pdf to the index; possible analysis error.",
"code":400
}
}

I have used the same schema file, manage_schema.xml to index the same documents without any errors. But why I got many analysis errors once I renamed this file to schema.xml file. The commands I used to create the collection and index the documents in Windows are as follows:

a) bin\solr start -m 4g -p 8983

b) bin\solr create_core -c saletent -d C:\Solr\archives\saletent\conf

c) java -Dc=saletent -Drecursive -Dauto -classpath server\solr-webapp\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\solr-core-9.4.0.jar org.apache.solr.cli.SimplePostTool C:\Solr\saletent\USA*

Anyone has the similar problems before? Thanks.